# javascript "onclick" event fails just in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I'm correcting a webpage which has a bug, and I detected where is it, but I don't know the basis.

This js works perfect in Firefox and explorer, but not in Chrome.

So, here we go:

--HTML--

```
<div id='mesa' onclick='gotoSection( mesa  )' >
```

--JAVASCRIPT--

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function gotoSection( section ){
        alert( section );
        $( '#section_container div' ).css( "display" , "none" );
        $( section ).css( "display" , "block" );
    }
</script>
```

--

So, in Firefox, the alert says "[object HTMLDivElement]", but in Chrome the alert says "undefined".

Comment: In your onclick , you should write `gotoSection($('#mesa'))` or use `this`

Comment: Or use the proper `.click()`/`.on()` methods as you're using jQuery..

Comment: So it depends on whether 'mesa' is defined in the global scope (so that the onclick can reach it). Don't you mean 'gotoSection(this)'?

Comment: Have you tried alert($(section)); - I don't see how else it is supposed to determine that "mesa" is an ID tag...it could be anything!

Comment: Could you build a fiddle ? I see no error on Chrome [with your exact code](http://jsbin.com/abodun/4/edit). What's your version of Chrome ?

Comment: Don't think about using "this" pointer, because gotoSection() must change another div properties. I think developer identified this div in an erroneus way, because there are two divs of each id, and this div is just an "button"

Comment: *"there are two divs of each id"* ? Here's your problem. That's illegal. Don't give the same id to more than one element.

Comment: Thank you for your help!. I think that there are lot of problems at the code, it mixes php + javascript + html + jquery in a very bad way. After my question I detected some id's duplicated, and another kind of errors which could Chrome goes Mad. I fixed something here, Something there, refactoring some code, and now, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`<div id='mesa' onclick='gotoSection( "#mesa"  )' >`

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
<div id='mesa' onclick='gotoSection( mesa  )' >
```

to

```
<div id='mesa' onclick='gotoSection( this  )' >
```

Note that when using jQuery, this would have been more idiomatic (it requires the element to be defined before you execute this line of code) :

```
$('#mesa').on('click', gotoSection);
```

---

**EDIT :**

Following your comment it's obvious now that your bug is that you gave the same id to more than one element. It's illegal and there's no guarantee, whatever the browser, on **which** element you will get using `$('#mesa')`.

Here's for example a solution :

```
<div id=mesaOpener> ... </div>
<div id=anotherDivOpener> ... </div>

 <div id=mesa> ... </div>
<div id=anotherDiv> ... </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('[id$=Opener]').on('click', function(){
        $('#section_container div' ).hide();
        $('#'+this.id.slice(0,4)).show();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Clicking on `<somename>Opener` shows the div `<somename>`.

Comment: *"...this would have been more idiomatic"* and have the advantage that it doesn't require `gotoSection` to be global. :-)

Comment: *"Not all browsers create a window property for each element with an `id`."* That may or may not be true (which ones don't?), but Chrome **does** create those properties: http://jsbin.com/abodun/1 ([source](http://jsbin.com/abodun/1/edit)). So in theory, that's not what's going on here. Still, though, using `this` should solve it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You're right. Even `<div id='mesa' onclick='gotoSection( mesa  )' >` [does work both on FF and Chrome](http://jsbin.com/abodun/4/edit). I don't see what happens here.

Comment: It shouldn't work with this pointer, because gotoSection() must work with another set of divs at the page. The code is really bad, and there are lot of mistakes. I'm going to refactor everything, because the code is very crazy.

Comment: @GerSoto See my edited answer. I think it does what you want.

Comment: yeah!!! I'm very sorry because I've started with an erroneos clue... But I didn't realized the code's quality till now... Now I'm refactoring every line of code ... I inspected the page and it's very very very bad done...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be mesa a string? I mean onclick='gotoSection("mesa")'

Answer (score 0):

$(section) - section can be a string(id selector) or valid dom object.
IE and Firefox have an interesting quirk : You can directly use id as the js reference to the dom object without explicit getElementById - for eg. mesa here refers to the div object.

Chrome/Safari donot support this.

Comment: See discussion below my answer : at least in recent version of chrome it does support it (which I find unfortunate).

Comment: I think it's been there a long time, there are too many pages that rely on it.